# I am a girl into music and art

Tags: sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

A more complex version of this line appeared in someone's cover letter. I found it odd for some reason but I can't be sure what that reason is.

> I am a girl into music and art.

I corrected it to "I am a girl who is into music and art." which sounds better to me. I would like to know if the original works. On the other hand, "I am a girl into my late 20s." and "I am a girl into my my fifth month of pregnancy." both sound natural and idiomatic to me, so is it just me?

Comment: The original works in the sense that we know what it means but it is not grammatical. Your version is correct. Of your other suggestions, both would improve if you changed **into** to **in**.  Pedants might argue for **woman** but that's nothing to do with grammar.

Comment: This is sometimes called ["whiz-deletion"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whiz-deletion).

Answer (score 2):

"I am a girl into music and art" is understandable, although I think "*who is* into music and art" is more natural and idiomatic.

*Into* meaning "interested in" is an idiomatic expression that does not translate to other uses.  *Into* normally means something like "*moving* from the outside of something to the inside."

"I am a girl into my late 20s" doesn't make sense, because you aren't *into* your late 20s (you are not moving or changing), you're simply *in* your late 20s.

Similarly, "I am a girl into my my fifth month of pregnancy" doesn't work, because you're *in* your fifth month of pregnancy, not *into* it.

You can only use *into* in a sentence like "I lived in Germany into my late 20s", which implies that you lived in Germany before your late 20s and continued to live there until you were in your late 20s.